# Big O complexity of for nested loop

Tags: complexity-theory

I must find the Big O complexity for this loop:

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    for(j=0; j<n-i; j++)
        print(i)
```

I think it's O(n^2), but I'm not really sure. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What was your reasoning for O(n^2)? (- which is correct)

Comment: I calculated that the inner for is done n times when i=0, n-1 times when i=1 and so on, so n+(n-1)+(n-2)....+1 (when i=n-1) which is equal to (n(n+1))/2. This is equal to n^2/2 + n/2 which led me to think that the whole code is O(n^2).

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, the complexity is `O(n^2)`.

- The first loop (`for(i=0; i<n; i++)`) is pretty easy. That is `O(n)`.
- The second loop (`for(j=0; j<n-i; j++)`) is trickier: It is (theoretically) `O(n - i)`.

When you combine those two, you will end up with:

```
O = n^2 - i*n
```

Since the Bit O notation only takes the largest factor, you simply remove the `- i*n` and end up with:

```
O(n^2)
```

Comment: This reasoning is incorrect since `i` is always changing (however the end result is still correct). Relying on naive multiplication of loops won't always work.